# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. - Laravel Lumen Mail

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen, illuminate

I seem to be a little stumped with an issue that I'm having with installing mail into my Laravel lumen project

```
composer require illuminate/mail
Using version ^7.8 for illuminate/mail
./composer.json has been updated
Gathering patches from patch file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/mail v7.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/mail v7.8.0
    - Conclusion: remove illuminate/container v6.18.10
    - Installation request for illuminate/mail ^7.8 -> satisfiable by illuminate/mail[7.x-dev, v7.8.0, v7.8.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v6.18.10
    - illuminate/mail 7.x-dev requires illuminate/container ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.8.1].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[7.x-dev, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.1, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.2, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.3, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.4, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.5, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.6, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.7, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.0.8, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.1, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.2, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.1.3, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.1, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.2.2, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.3.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.4.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.1, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.5.2, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.1, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.6.2, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.7.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.7.1, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.8.0, v6.18.10].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/container[v7.8.1, v6.18.10].
    - Installation request for illuminate/container (locked at v6.18.10) -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v6.18.10].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I've tried everything I can think of but now I'm out of ideas if anyone has any suggestions or could lead me into the right direction that will be great

Comment: which version of Lumen are you using?

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Which parts of that message are unclear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an older version of Lumen, which is not supported by the current version of `illuminate/mail`.

You need to install the latest version that supports `illuminate/container v6.18.10`
If you check in the latest revision tags for this package, the earliest version that supports `illuminate/container v6.18.10` is this one: https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/v6.18.10/composer.json where you can find the line

```
    "require": {
        ...
        "illuminate/container": "^6.0",
        ...
    },
```

For you to install this specific version, you need to use:

```
composer require illuminate/mail:6.18.10
```

Comment: You Sir are a god thank you I've been tearing my hair out thank you so much